# General node.js data to mysql with stringify & escape

Tags: mysql, escaping, stringify

I need a better understanding about stringify, escape and storing in mysql database. The task looked easy but with escaping I run into some trouble. So I would be happy for general explanation of the following questions:

What I try is to store a javascript object in a mysql DB. It works fine with stringify prior to send. Getting it back from the DB just parse it and everything is fine.

```
let myObj = {
  name: 'Paul',
  age: '24'
}
```

Now, I have additionally a message in my object, which can have special characters:

```
let myObj = {
  name: 'Paul',
  age: '24',
  message: 'message with special characters: ',`´"~'
}
```

Also no problem, I started to escape. The result:

```
let myObj = {
  name: 'Paul',
  age: '24',
  message: 'message with special characters: \'\,\`´\"\~'
}
```

If I do stringify the object, I get following result:

```
{
   "name": "Paul",
   "age": "24",
   "message": "message with special characters: \\'\\,\\`´\\\"\\~"
 }
```

Sending it to mysql DB gives following error:

**(node:13077) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\,\`´\"\~"}**

Due to the error I manipulated the special characters and removed the additional `'\'` which gives following result:

```
obj.message = obj.message(/\\\\/g,'\\');
```

output:

```
 {
   "name": "Paul",
   "age": "24",
   "message": "message with special characters: \'\,\`´\\"\~"
 }
```

everything is fine and the data is transfered to the DB and my mysql update query has no failure anymore.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a better way dealing with escaping inside an object, which will be stringified and send to a mysql DB?
2. If yes, how is it done? Or is there no other way as to remove the additional backslashes inserted due to the stringify?

**One step further. The message has included a new line: `\n`:**

output stringified:

```
 {
   "name": "Paul",
   "age": "24",
   "message": "message with special characters: \'\,\`´\n\\"\~"
 }
```

Sending it to the DB I get following entry (Where \n: I get a new line):

```
{"name":"Paul","age":"24","message":"message with special characters: ',`´ 
\"~"}
```

Which results in an error parsing it back. here is the log (serverside) prior parsing (error makes sense):

```
{"name":"Paul","age":"24","message":"\',`´\n' +
'\\"~"}
```

**Question**:

1. Regarding the upper part, what do I have to do, to get the `\n` also escaped? Which means, that the DB entry is correct and the DB doesn't take the `\n` to start a new line?

Happy for any explaning / help!

Comment: The second part concerning how to escape '\n' or '\b' before sending them to the DB is managed by escaping them 4 times: /\\n/g,'\\\\n'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how's the correct way or the easy way, but that's how I did it when I needed to insert a user generated field as a JSON in a MYSQL database

```
string_cleanJSON_preStringify(str)
{
   if(!str.replace) return str;

   str=str.replace(/'/g,"\\'"); //escape all at least ' once
   str=str.replace(/"/g,'\\"'); //escape all at least " once

   str=str.replace(/[\t\r\n\f]/g,''); // remove problematic escape characters

   if(str.charAt(str.length-1) == '\\') str+=' '; // add blank space at the end if \ is last character - for example: {"var":"\"} would be problematic

    return str;
}

string_cleanJSON_to_query(str)
{


   str = str.replace(/(\\)+\\/g,'\\'); // replace all \ more than 1 in a row, to be just 1 ( \\ -> gets escaped again when it's processed to just \)

   str = str.replace(/(\\)+"/g,'\\\\\\"'); // replace all \" more than 1 (ex \\\") - i don't know why \\\\\\ - this seem to work in my case, might need to alter based on str manipulations before insert


   str = str.replace(/(\\)+'/g,"\\'"); // i don't know why \\ - this seem to work in my case, might need to alter based on str manipulations before insert


   str = str.replace(/(\\)+t/g,"t"); // same process as above but with problematic escape characters

   str = str.replace(/(\\)+r/g,"r");
   str = str.replace(/(\\)+n/g,"n");
   str = str.replace(/(\\)+f/g,"f");
   
   



   return str;

}
```

How I use this to get a query:

```
let o = {field_data:string_cleanJSON_preStringify(user_gen_field_data)}
let j = string_cleanJSON_to_query(JSON.stringify(o));
let q = `INSERT INTO blabla (json) VALUES('${j}')`;
```